# Result of join linq query to a viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, list

In my action method I am running the following query which returns a list :

```
var list = db.WorkRoles.
                Join(db.WorkRolesUsersDetails,
                o => o.WorkRoleId, od => od.WorkRoleId,
                (o, od) => new
                {
                    WorkRoleId = o.WorkRoleId,
                    RoleName = o.RoleName,
                    RoleDescription = o.RoleDescription,
                    CompanyId = o.CompanyId,
                    WRUDId = od.WRUDId,
                    UserDetailsId = od.UserDetailsId,
                    FocusStart = od.FocusStart,
                    FocusEnd = od.FocusEnd
                }).ToList();
```

I have a viemodel in the same format looking like this :

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public RoleViewModel(int workRoleId, string roleName, string roleDescription, int companyId, int wRUDId, string userDetailsId, DateTime focusStart, DateTime focusEnd)
    {
        WorkRoleId = workRoleId;
        RoleName = roleName;
        RoleDescription = roleDescription;
        CompanyId = companyId;
        WRUDId = wRUDId;
        UserDetailsId = userDetailsId;
        FocusStart = focusStart;
        FocusEnd = focusEnd;
    }
    int WorkRoleId { get; set; }
    string RoleName  { get; set; }
    string RoleDescription { get; set; }
    int CompanyId { get; set; }
    int WRUDId { get; set; }
    string UserDetailsId { get; set; }
    DateTime FocusStart { get; set; }
    DateTime FocusEnd { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to convert the result of my query to a list of my viewmodel?

One thing I've tried from answers here on stackoverflow is :

```
var list = db.WorkRoles.
                Join(db.WorkRolesUsersDetails,
                o => o.WorkRoleId, od => od.WorkRoleId,
                (o, od) => new
                {
                    WorkRoleId = o.WorkRoleId,
                    RoleName = o.RoleName,
                    RoleDescription = o.RoleDescription,
                    CompanyId = o.CompanyId,
                    WRUDId = od.WRUDId,
                    UserDetailsId = od.UserDetailsId,
                    FocusStart = od.FocusStart,
                    FocusEnd = od.FocusEnd
                }).ToList()
                .Select(item => new RoleViewModel(
                   item.WorkRoleId,
                    item.RoleName,
                    item.RoleDescription,
                    item.CompanyId,
                    item.WRUDId,
                    item.UserDetailsId,
                    item.FocusStart,
                    item.FocusEnd));
```

But, sadly, what this got mew wasn't a list og `RoleViewModel`s. Here's a copy from the value part in the debugger :

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<<>f__AnonymousType6<int, string, string, int, int, string, System.DateTime, System.DateTime>, eksp.Models.RoleViewModel>}
```

Comment: Put `.ToList()` at end of your code.

Comment: Why not just `(o, od) => new RoleViewModel { ....}).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `ToList` to get the list of your items. You are assigning the *query* to your `list` variable. The query is deferred, that means it will not be executed until you actually retrieve a result with a call to `ToList`, `ToArray`, `First` etc.:

```
List<RoleViewModel> list = db.WorkRoles.
                Join(db.WorkRolesUsersDetails,
                o => o.WorkRoleId, od => od.WorkRoleId,
                (o, od) => new
                {
                    WorkRoleId = o.WorkRoleId,
                    RoleName = o.RoleName,
                    RoleDescription = o.RoleDescription,
                    CompanyId = o.CompanyId,
                    WRUDId = od.WRUDId,
                    UserDetailsId = od.UserDetailsId,
                    FocusStart = od.FocusStart,
                    FocusEnd = od.FocusEnd
                }).ToEnumerable()
                .Select(item => new RoleViewModel(
                   item.WorkRoleId,
                    item.RoleName,
                    item.RoleDescription,
                    item.CompanyId,
                    item.WRUDId,
                    item.UserDetailsId,
                    item.FocusStart,
                    item.FocusEnd)).ToList();
```

The best tip I can give you: Avoid using `var` and specify the types explicitly where you can. If you would have done that, your compiler would have given you an error.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. And thanks for the tip as well :)

Comment: And the first `ToList` can be `AsEnumerable` to prevent building a useless intermediate result.

Comment: @GertArnold: It actually can be dropped completely. I'll edit the reply.

Comment: But then EF will complain about not using a parameterless constructor. You have to decouple the second part from the part that's executed as expression.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot. I am used to initializers, not constructors. Editing again :P.

Comment: Another acceptable alternative (for EF) would be to simply replace the first `new` by  `new RoleViewModel`.

Comment: @GertArnold: Yes, that's right in this case and that's how I would do it. If you put some other LINQ methods between `Join` and `Select`, an intermediate class might make sense.